# How to copy the text in ubuntu error window?

Tags: xubuntu, bug-reporting

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit, VLC media player 2.1.2 Rincewind (revision 2.1.2-0-ga4c4876).

VLC crashes on startup and gives this error

> 12836 segmentation fault (core dumped)  vlc

While that message may be enough I'd like to copy the text shown here in order to open a bug report and make sure that the dev team has more than enough information on what's going on (select all -> copy)

[image]

It's impossible to take screenshot of the whole window, it's just too big, I'm sure that these errors are in some logs somewhere.

But I'd like to know how to copy them right from that window. I also know that I could just send the error by ticking the checkbox and the dev team will be notified, but I'd like to manually open a ticket and communicate with them. If there's one thing I hate about computers it's bots, bots everywhere, no need for communication anymore!

Even if the vlc error is easy to fix, and even if it's not really a bug, I still would like to know how to copy the text.

Comment: Notice, I didn't use the vlc tag, because it's not about vlc in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to copy and paste anything, the bug reporting tool handles that for you.

That text is there for you to scan the text files so that you know *exactly* what is being sent to errors.ubuntu.com.

If you want to do it by hand you can file a bug manually and then do `ubuntu-bug 12345`, that number being the bug number you want to attach the information to. If you're looking for the files, they'll be in `/var/crash`.

But really, the automated tools are there for a reason, it's to cut out human error, etc. Usually just submitting the trace and letting the Launchpad retracers do their job is enough. Humans tend to not scale.

Comment: the thing with bots, I can't communicate with them, can't ask them how to resolve the issue, can't ask them when should I expect the issue to be resolved, can't ask them if the daily builds work perfectly, maybe the issue is solved in a beta version that I can't download using `apt-get install vlc` because it's not stable yet. Sometimes you need to speak personally with the programmers,

Comment: @Fischer Sure, I get that. The best thing to do in that case is to get the information there with the automatic tools, and then ping an ubuntu mailing list for the humans.

Comment: And request to make possible to enable copy-paste is at https://bugs.launchpad.net/apport/+bug/1133184 (with possibility to vote for it) (useful for googling to solve problem to report issues for packages maintained by developers of software etc)